# MS Word odd ole container alignment issues when closing word side panels

Tags: delphi, ms-word, ole

I am not sure whether this a delphi specific problem. I have a form with a top aligned toolbar and  alClient aligned OleContainer. When I open the form and load Word into the olecontainer it is aligned correctly and the Word object appears as you would expect.

If you then open any of the word side panels (eg F1 to open the help panel on the right, Ctrl+F to open search on left etc) these open correctly and reduce the size of the word document accordingly to accommodate themselves, but when you close a side panel, the word document does not resize to reclaim the space occupied by that panel. Adding a function to realign the container does nothing.

It is clear that the word side panels (and indeed the ribbon itself) are not opened within the ole container.

I have searched on Google and found a suggestion to create a sub form within a client aligned panel and parenting the container to the sub form, but this does not overcome the document realignment issue when a Word side panel is closed.

Comment: Still unable to resolve this issue. The OleContainer is parented directly to the form and client aligned. Opening one of the Word side panels causes the size of the OLEContainer to shrink to make room on the form for the Word side panel. However, it remains client aligned . When the panel is closed despite it being client aligned it does not expand into the vacant space. By calling the DoVerb procedure of the OLEContainer it "reloads" the word app and does expand into the vacant space. However the effect of this is visually and practically unattractive and in any event difficult to implement.

Comment: I did read on one site that there was (some years ago) a bug with OleContainer and that a fix had been issued, but it did not clarify what the bug was, what the fix was and where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a sort of solution to the realignment problem following closure of side panels. It involves calling the ole container's doVerb method in order to refresh the document within the container. However, this is visually unattractive and slightly time consuming and should only be called when necessary ie when a Word side pane is actually closed. This is not easy to detect. There are no VBA events etc. It involves a mouse hook to intercept mouse down with an analysis of the window that is below the mouse. Unfortunately, the window classes and window captions of the exit button on the various Word side panes is the same as the overall tool bar which also usually contains a drop down menu to allow moving, resizing and closing. The drop down menu has a different class name, but each of the menu items has the same classname as the menu. In short, it is impossible to tell from class names alone whether the exit button has been clicked. The cludge that I have come up with is to add a timer with an interval of around 250 milliseconds. The hook function enables the timer and the timer event checks to see if the side panel has disappeared. I have set out the code I have devised for doing this. I am sure it could well be improved upon.

Within the hook procedure:

```
var 
      hw: hwnd;
      clsName, wText: array [0 .. 255] of Char;
      PT: tpoint;
begin
      GetCursorPos(pt);
      HW:= WindowFromPoint (PT);
      GetClassName (HW, clsName, 256);
      GetWindowText (HW, wText, 256);
      if (uppercase(clsName) = 'MSOCOMMANDBAR')
      Or ((uppercase(clsName) = 'MSOCOMMANDBARPOPUP') 
      And (uppercase(wText) = 'WORKPANE OPTIONS MENU')) then begin
            HookMsg.Result := 0;           
            Timer1.Enabled := true;

      end;     
end;
```

Within the onTimer event:

```
var
      PT: TPoint;
      HW: hwnd;
      clsName, wText: array [0 .. 255] of Char;

begin
      timer1.Enabled:=false;
      GetCursorPos(PT);
      Hdl := WindowFromPoint (PT);
      GetClassName (HW, clsName, 256);
      GetWindowText (HW, wText, 256);
      if (uppercase(clsName) <> 'MSOCOMMANDBAR')
      And (uppercase(clsName) <> 'MSOCOMMANDBARPOPUP') 
      And (uppercase(wText) <> 'WORKPANE OPTIONS MENU') then
    OLEContainer1.DoVerb(ovSHow);
end;
```

As far as I can work out the two class names are identical for all the Word side panes.